# HTTP Get in AngularJs Could not located the Json file

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have tried several times with the following code to get the json data.

```
var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp", []);

    todoApp.run(function($http) {

        $http.get('todo.json').success(function (data) {

            model.items = data;
        });
    });
```

here todo.json file is located on the root of the project....what wrong i am doing?

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: please provide the error?

Comment: i have checked there, the message was file not found...

Comment: Alright, is there something unclear about this message?

Comment: Is the url is correct on which get call is going?

Comment: 404 not found error.....

Comment: Provide us your project hierarchy

Comment: the that i have calling is on the root of the project and the file which calling the json file is also on the root of the project

Comment: ProjectName->todo.html, todo.json..............here todo.html call the todo.json file and both file is under the root of the project directory

Comment: you are using visual studio with IIS Express ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*if you are using visual studio with IIS Express* to debug then you will have to add a mime type for the static json file otherwise this debug server wont know how to handle the request for this type of file.
you can do by 

1.Adding a new web config file in your project (if it dosent exist)
2.Adding this inside the file

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="text/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

under config section / tag. More info about this [here](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VLZyWLCqaxbxmUjWIvez?p=preview) I've put up with your situation.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('data.json').success(function(response){
        $scope.items = response;
      });
    });
```